# Split IObservable<byte[]> to characters then to line

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Rx is great, but sometime it's hard to find the elegant way to do something. The idea is quite simple. I receive events with a byte[], this array might contains part of a line, multiple lines or one line. What I want is find a way to have an IObservable of Line so `IObservable<String>`, where each element of the sequence will be a line.

After hours the closest solution I found is pretty ugly, and off course doesn't work because **scan** trigger OnNext on every char :

```
//Intermediate subject use to transform byte[] into char
var outputStream = new Subject<char>();
_reactiveSubcription = outputStream
    //Scan doesn't work it trigger OnNext on every char
    //Aggregate doesn't work neither as it doesn't return intermediate result
    .Scan(new StringBuilder(), (builder, c) => c == '\r' ? new StringBuilder() : builder.Append((char)c))
    .Subscribe(this);


Observable.FromEventPattern<ShellDataEventArgs>(shell, "DataReceived")
            //Data is a byte[]
            .Select(_ => _.EventArgs.Data)
            .Subscribe(array => array.ToObservable()
            //Convert into char
            .ForEach(c => outputStream.OnNext((char)c)));
```

Note : `_reactiveSubcription` should be the `IObservable<String>`.

Without considering character encoding issues, what am I missing to make this work ?

Comment: What you are trying to do in one elegant chunk has never worked in my real world stations.    
How do you know that the byte[] is all received or where its end bytes are?   i.e. will a 2K msg arrive in two 1K chunks on two different events in the middle of a Line.   I always have to pop the bytes into a theoretical infinite queue and look for my  NewLine or CrLf within this other built up array and then pull the individual Lines out as the NewLines and CrLf chars show up.   I then have to put safety code to clear the built up array if No NewLine or CrLf shows up within my MaxLineSize value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me.

First, Convert the byte[] into a string and Split the string on `\r` (Regex Split keeps the delimiters).

Now there is a stream of Strings some of which end in `\r`.

Then Concat, to keep them in order. Also, since `strings` needs to be Hot for the next step, Publish them.

```
var strings = bytes.
  Select(arr => (Regex.Split(Encoding.Default.GetString(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1), "(\r)")).
    Where(s=> s.Length != 0).
    ToObservable()).
  Concat().
  Publish().
  RefCount();
```

Make a Window of strings that ends when a string ends with `\r`. `strings` needs to be hot since it is used for both the Window contents and the end-of-window trigger.

```
var linewindows = strings.Window(strings.Where(s => s.EndsWith("\r")));
```

Aggregate each Window into a single string.

```
var lines = linewindows.SelectMany(w => w.Aggregate((l, r) => l + r));
```

`lines` is `IObservable<String>` and each string contains one line.

To test this I used the following generator to produce `IObservable<byte[]>`

```
var bytes = Observable.
Range(1, 10).
SelectMany(i => Observable.
    Return((byte)('A' + i)).
    Repeat(24).
    Concat(Observable.
        Return((byte)'\r'))).
Window(17).
SelectMany(w => w.ToArray());
```